# UIScrollView is not scrolling the content of another subview

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, subviews

Hi everyone. I dragged a `UIScrollView` to my storyboard, then I added a `UIView` on top of that `UIScrollView`. This `UIView` loads another subview dynamically depending on what the server throws to this app.

The problem is the `UIScrollView` is not scrolling the content, even though I made the loaded `UIView` bigger than the `UIScrollView`. I'm not invoking `[myScroller addSubView:myUiView]`. Am I doing it right? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you set the content size of the scroll view?

Comment: @Wain i just set it on the viewDidLoad: ` myScroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width*myUiView.frame.size.width, 1500);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For every time you change the content try calling

```
//removeFromSuperview the UIView was set as content view
self.myScroller.contentSize = self.myUiView.frame.size;
[myScroller addSubView:myUiView];
```

Don't forget to link **both** views on Interface Builder

**PS:** In this apporach the subView must not be inside the scrollView on IB

Comment: Thanks a lot that worked!! the problem was that the content view was inside de scrolling view on IB...Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You must set the content size of the scroll view.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your view controller.

```
- (void) viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

    myScroller.contentSize = CGSizeMake(CGRectGetMaxX(myUiView.frame), CGRectGetMaxY(myUiView.frame));
}
```

Comment: I added it but nothing happens. I just connected the UIScrollView and the UIView to the view i added no code at all to handle the scroller could that be the problem?

Comment: yes. if myScroller and myUiView were not connected to the view controller this wouldn't work. They have to be connected for it to work.

Comment: also make sure scrolling is enabled on interface builder or add the following to viewDidLoad.  myScroller.scrollEnabled = YES;

Comment: yes, everything is connected i added the scrollEnabled i even printed the myUiView height and its 1500, the myScroller height is 585 and still not scrolling.